# how to match strings from different tables considering the spaces,hyphons,dot etc in oracle

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables G1DM and S1DM. I want to match the NAME column in G1DM and S1DM with maximum number of matches. The problem is that the whole name with initial is given for S1DM but in G1DM the initial is given in another column as ABBREVI. I should match maximum number of names from both tables by considering the spaces etc.. because an entry ARUNKUMAR A R  in S1DM is given as ARUN KUMAR in G1DM and its initial is given in ABBREVI. Later I need to match the names who also has DOB as common.Please provide a solution.

I am using Oracle.

**TABLES:**

1)***S1DM***

**NAME**

ABDUL RASHEED K

ARUN ALPHONSE

ARUN BHASKAR

ARUNKUMAR A R

CHANDRASEKHARAN P

DILEEPAN P

E B PRASAD

JEYAKUMAR K

JOE KURUVILLA EASOW

JOHN N V

LEKHA R

LILA KUMARY S

NISHA A K

NOUSAD M

PRASAD R

RADHAMONI A K

RAJEESH T

RAJESH M G

REJI V KURIAKOSE

RENI LUKOSE

RENJITH P

SASIDHARAN V M

SHAJAHAN A

SHIJU K K

SHINOI K R

SIDHAKUMAR V

SOMASUNDARAM P

SUJITH KUMAR J S

WILSON MATHEW T

**DOB**
30-05-79

05-11-81

30-05-82

27-05-79

21-11-55

15-05-81

24-05-62

07-05-68

15-02-62

20-05-63

29-05-59

01-06-58

17-09-61

31-05-71

26-05-64

26-05-59

26-05-74

30-05-73

01-04-76

17-03-81

16-03-80

27-09-59

12-05-59

31-05-79

04-04-76

25-05-78

21-05-59

20-04-80

02-01-60

***2)G1DM***

**NAME**

ABDUL RASHEED

ARUN ALPHONSE

ARUN BHASKAR

ARUN KUMAR

DANIEL DEVARAJ

DILEEPAN

JEYAKUMAR

JOE KURUVILLA EASOW

JOHN

NOUSAD

PRASAD

PRASAD

RADHAMONI

RAJEESH

RAJESH

REJI.V.KURIAKOSE

RENI LUKOSE

SASIDHARAN

SATHYAN

SHAJAHAN

SHIJU

SIDHAKUMAR

SIVANANDAN

SOMASUNDARAM

SUJITH KUMAR

SUSHAMAKUMARI

WILSON MATHEW

**ABBEVI**

K

NULL

NULL

A.R

NULL

P

K

NULL

N.V

M

E.B

R

A.K

T

M.G

NULL

NULL

V.M.

P K

A.

K.K.

V.

K.

P.

J.S.

S.

T.

**DOB**

30-05-79

05-11-81

30-05-82

27-05-79

20-08-55

15-05-81

07-05-68

15-02-62

20-05-63

31-05-71

24-05-62

26-05-64

26-05-59

26-05-74

30-05-73

01-04-76

17-03-81

27-09-59

20-05-57

12-05-59

31-05-79

25-05-78

09-12-57

21-05-59

20-04-80

30-04-57

02-01-60

The queries I used are:

**select c.name,b.name from S1DM c inner join G1DM on c.name like concat('%',b.name);**

**select c.name,b.name from S1DM c inner join G1DM  b on((c.name like concat(b.name,'%'))and c.dob = b.dob);**

By using these I got entries but the name Prasad comes twice.. and ARUNKUMAR also is not matched..Please give me a solution

Comment: I don't think what you want is posible. You can have thousand of possible combination of spaces (even millons). Specially with ARUNKUMAR you can have a space between every character. You can try to write a small code on C# to generate thoose combinations and try to match. I would recommend correct the data on the table and not try to write complex combinatory code.

Comment: oh is it.. so its not possible to use a query to find the matches. I will try updating the table and shall try again .thank you so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the comments stating otherwise, this is fairly straightforward.  Since you're using Oracle, you can use a combination of `TRIM` and `REPLACE` to get rid of the dots out of the abbrevi column.  There are two cases your join needs to consider - in some of your data, the initials come before the name, and in some, they come after the name.  I suggest using `IN` to cover both cases.

Your query could be written like this, if it didn't have to match ARUNKUMAR with ARUN KUMAR.

```
SELECT c.name, b.name 
FROM   S1DM c JOIN G1DM b 
ON  c.name IN ( 
    TRIM( REPLACE(b.abbrevi, '.', ' ') || ' ' || b.name), 
    TRIM( b.name || ' ' || REPLACE(b.abbrevi, '.', ' ')))
AND c.dob = b.dob
```

To deal with the case where the spaces don't match between the two names, you could eliminate the spaces entirely, from both names.  That would then look something like this.

```
SELECT c.name, b.name 
FROM   S1DM c JOIN G1DM b 
ON  REPLACE(c.name, ' ', '') IN ( 
    REPLACE(b.abbrevi, '.', '') || REPLACE(b.name, ' ', ''), 
    REPLACE(b.name, ' ', '') || REPLACE(b.abbrevi, '.', ''))
AND c.dob = b.dob
```

Comment: 23 results need to be obtained since 23 of the entries matches when all the special characters and spaces are considered. By using the 1st query I got 21 results correctly except "ARUNKUMAR A R" from G1DM  and "REJI V KURIAKOSE" from both tables.

Comment: OK, ARUNKUMAR is the reason why I gave you the second query.  It should match him.  As far as REJI V KURIAKOSE is concerned, it looks like the issue is some dots in `b.name`, so I think you'll need to `REPLACE` the dots in that too.  Now that I've shown you the technique,  you should be able to work this out for yourself.

Comment: yeah "." is the problem.. "." comes in between  REJI V KURIAKOSE now am trying to replace it. Trying now...Thank you David for your help...

Comment: You're very welcome, Reenu.  Good luck with your ongoing learning, and feel free to ask again if you get stuck again.

Comment: SELECT c.name, b.name 
FROM   S1DM c JOIN G1DM b 
ON  REPLACE(c.name, ' ', '') IN ( 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.ABBREVI, '.', ''), ' ', ''), '-','') || REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.name, ' ', ''), '.',''), '-',''),
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.name, ' ', ''), '.',''), '-','') ||  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.ABBREVI, '.', ''), ' ', ''), '-',''))
    and c.dob=b.dob;    David, I used this query. Got 100 % result

Comment: thank you David.. trying to extract other values also it works fine for a small part of the database... I will give it a try for the entire db and inform you ok..

Comment: OK, I look forward to hearing how you get on.